# ILMerge, Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: System.Runtime

Tags: .net, sqlite-net, ilmerge

I'm getting this exception during merging my project's executable file with the `SQLite-net.dll` file.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt4cA.png)

Does anyone have a solution?

EDIT: I added a config file containing this:

```
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <requiredRuntime safemode="true" imageVersion="v4.0.30319" version="v4.0.30319"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

to the ILMerge folder and a new exception occured

`Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: SQLitePCLRaw.core`

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKEKX.png)

Comment: https://stevemichelotti.com/ilmerge-unresolved-assembly-reference-not-allowed-system/

Comment: It is not the same error , but I will give it a try.